# How is the quality of a question automatically evaluated?

Tags: support, bug, quality-filter

When I try to post a question without any code only using plain text on Stack Overflow, it gives me a validation error:

> This post does not meet our quality standards.

OK I got it. Without any self effort and some sample code it doesn't meet the quality standards of Stack Overflow. But how come some questions are posted and some are not just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300874/locked-status-of-user-account-in-active-directory-using-winnt-in-c-sharp) question? I choose this question only as an example.

I'm just for curious which  validation/regex is used to validate question quality which makes these different judgements.

Comment: The automated filter is just an algorithm, it can't catch everything. But as you can see, the question you linked to is being taken care of by the site's human members

Answer (score 10):

The tool is automated and the details of the algorithm aren't public. Given your example, it obviously it isn't perfect.

You should focus on improving your question in general rather than looking at the algorithm to try and sneak around it. Try fixing your capitalization, punctuation, and having spaces after periods.